Проблемы с кодом для вк бота
Написал код, но не понимаю почему не обрабатываються сообщения
import vk_api
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
from config import Token_VK, group_id

def send_message (to_user_id, message):
    vk_session.method("messages.send", {"user_id": to_user_id, "message": message, "randing_id": 0})

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=Token_VK)
vk_bot = vk_session.get_api()
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, group_id)

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        message = event.obj.Text
        from_user_id = event.obj.from_id

        if message == "Start":
            vk_bot.send_message(from_user_id, "Это сообщение от сообщества")

Ошибки
requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.vk.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /method/groups.getLongPollServer (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000228C0D13B30>, 'Connection to api.vk.com timed out. (connect timeout=None)'))
Помогите решить

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

А где запускаете? Откуда вы запускаете там хотя бы хост api.vk.com пингуется? А телнетом если на его порт 443 попытаться зайти?

Если вы про приложение для написания кода то PyCharm
